# custom decorator for permission and login required

Tags: python, django, decorator, python-decorators

I'm following the "Django Unleashed Book" and I've created a custom decorator. I do struggle a little with understanding some parts of the code. The lack of understanding may result from a lack of python knowledge. Here is the code:

```
def require_authenticated_permission(permission):

def decorator(cls):
    if (not isinstance(cls, type)
            or not issubclass(cls, View)):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "require_authenticated_permission"
            " must be applied to subclasses "
            "of View class.")
    check_auth = method_decorator(login_required)
    check_perm = method_decorator(
            permission_required(
                permission,
                raise_exception=True))

    cls.dispatch = check_auth(check_perm(cls.dispatch))
    return cls

return decorator
```

I have one problem with understanding the code. 
The decorator takes a GCBV, uses the dispatch function and stores the GCBV in the "permission" object as an argument for "require_authenticated_permission". Then it takes the arguments from the GCBV (e. g. DetailView) and stores it in the "cls" object. Since there is only one cls object and not something like *args, I would expect the decorator to just work with one argument such as "class ThisIsAView(Detailview)" but it also works with views like this "class ThisIsAView(GetObjectMixin, Detailview)" ... this would mean that it stores both arguments in the cls object?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the decorator, `cls` is the class `ThisIsAView`, not the parent class `DetailView`. Therefore it doesn't matter whether you defined the class as:

```
class ThisIsAView(DetailView):
    ...
```

or

```
class ThisIsAView(MyMixin, DetailView):
    ...
```

You also say "the decorator stores the GCBV in the "permission" object as an argument for "require_authenticated_permission". That's doesn't sound quite right. The decorator is taking the GCBV's `dispatch` method, and wrapping it with the `permission_required` decorator and `login_required` decorator. It then replaces the CBV's `dispatch` method with this newly wrapped method.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. But I don't really understand all of it. In a python function decorator you would have two functions for a function that stores arguments, right (maybe this sounds rather confusion without code to explain). But there would be an outside function that would take the function (the one that is decorated) as an argument and then an inner function that would have the arguments of the function (the one that is decorated). Just assuming that you would want to decorate a function with arguments. Because of that behavior I thought the class would be permissions

Comment: and also I thought cls would be the argument of the class, is it would be with the function described. Why is the behavior different and cls equal to the class? Also I don't really understand what "permisions" is equal to in your explanation.

Comment: You might find it easier to look at this decorator without assuming that it works the same as a decorator for functions. The `decorator` function takes a class `cls`, modifies `cls.dispatch`, then returns `cls`. The outer function `require_authenticated_permission` defines `decorator` for a specific permission `permission` and returns `decorator`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. This behavior is really somewhat confusing. Maybe I fully understand it once i'm a little more familiar with Django and Python.